# Operation of the useEffect cycle

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have a function that retrieves messages from Firebase:

`getAddedMessages()`

This method receives only **UID** for messages from the database

This method calls another function:

`followThePik(messageId)`

The method accepts the messageId obtained in the previous message

When this is done, I update the information in State

`setNewMessage(message)`

Saves the content of the message to State

I prepared **useEffect** which is performed when **newMessage** is updated

```
useEffect(() => {
    //method 1
    //method async 2
    //method async 3
}, [newMessage]);
```

**useEffect** consists of various methods

INFORMATION:

There can be several new messages at once

I have such a problem that before it finishes calling all `useEffect`, further methods are performed

I have a single message saved in state `newMessage`. Before I use it in `useEffect`, another one inserts it and, as a last resort, the process works only for the last message

**Main question**

**Is there anything you can do to block further processes until the `useEffect` has been completed?**

Answer (score 0):

Two ways we can try

1. Try using a loading setState after the async calls are over in 
   useEffect().Based upon the value you can trigger the getAddedMessage 
   call.
2. Or else have the messages in an array after finishing that array canbe 
   iterated for useEffect()

Answer (score 0):

In your code newMessage was dependency for useEffect and every time it setState for message, it again fire the useEffect. So to avoid this make another method and call that method from useEffect in order to avoid dependency in useEffect

```
const completeProcess = () => 
{
   async method 1
   async method 2
   async method 3
}

useEffect(() => {
   completeProcess();
},[])
```